# not able to redirect to cart page inside controller method

Tags: magento-1.9

In one of my controller's method, I have:

```
$this->_redirect('checkout/cart', array("_forced_secure" => true));
```

Though, it doesn't work and redirects to `'checkout/account'` instead. I've also tried:

```
$this->_redirectUrl( Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart') );
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

use this below code :

```
$this->_redirectReferer();
```

or

```
$redirectUrl = $this->getUrl('checkout/cart');
$this->_redirectUrl($redirectUrl);
```

Comment: doesn't work, still redirecting to `checkout/account`